# click link in navbar menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, navbar

I'd like to use javascript to click on a link in a navbar dropdown menu. If the dropdown has been opened at least once `$("#state_save").is(":visible")` is `true` and I can use `document.getElementById("state_save").click();` to click the link.

However, without activating the navigation bar manually first, `document.getElementById("state_save").click();` won't work

I can get the list of all links in the navbar using `$("#nav_radiant li:has(a)")` but it is not clear how to click on `#state_save`.

EDIT:

Based on the comments I figured out that until the dropdown menu has been opened the href of the `state_save` element is blank.

Praveen: A (slightly) older version of the app is linked below. The id in this version is `saveStateNav`

https://vnijs.shinyapps.io/radiant/?SSUID=1f38b44126

FYI The code is generated using R and the [shiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com/) package

Comment: Does $("#nav_radiant li:has(a)") returns list of all <a> when $("#state_save").is(":visible") is false?

Can you please share sample code?

Comment: If you can get the list of all your clickable links, then you should be able to go through and determine which one has id = state_save, pull that one out of the array of links, then execute click on it.

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to simulate a click? Or could you be firing off the related function/redirect in javascript instead of a click activated event?